# Fullscreen adaptive CSS layout

Tags: html, css

I want to set up a certain CSS layout described by the following:

1. it is table-structured, so there are a number of rows each having certain amount of cells; cells borders in different rows possibly do not align;
2. it is fullscreen; not like occupying whole device display, but rather using all the window space present - the window height should be divided in rows and its length should be divided in cells (full-window would be a more precise term)
3. it is adaptive; meaning, heights and lengths are given as percentage from window dimensions; this also applies to margins, paddings, etc.

More accurately, I am trying to make a web-chat application consisting of message area, list of online users, text input and "send" button. I want each of these components to have space of certain (relative to window dimesions) length between them and between window borders and components adjacent to them (that is, margins). I want this layout to persist precisely after zooming or resizing the window.

I do realize that this could be achieved with Javascript (which I am capable of), but I assume that would be ugly and less efficient, so I would like to use CSS (if possible).

So far I tried:

1. marking up the window with `inline-block` wrappers containing the actual visible elements; didn't really work because setting wrapped content's width and height to 100% results in them expanding the wrappers (regarding borders and margins), which ruins the layout instantly; I understand I could try 98%, 97.5%, 97.2%, etc. but this is not precise so it really bugs me
2. using floating divs (same as above)
3. using `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell` divs; did not satisfy my requirements because only absolute values work this way

I am really a newb, so I might have missed a number of obvious points here.

Comment: This question is probably worthy of closing for being too broad as it stands. Please edit your question to include the code you've tried so far that comes as close as you've gotten to what you want and describe its shortcomings. A picture of your desired layout would also be great because your description is a bit vague. (For example, how many cells is "a certain amount"?)

Comment: @cjl750 I specified in my question that I want to make a web-chat app, which requires me to arrange four containers in two rows and two columns. I will provide a picture later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, using Javascript looks like the only reasonable option here.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the vh and vw measurments,
they can be used like this:

```
height 10vh;
width 100vw;
```

this would make a row that's 1/10th of the screen tall and 100% wide.

Comment: I am concerned about this not being supported by some browsers.

Comment: Viewport measurments are now widely supported. shouldn't have a problem.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: >iOS 7 Safari sets viewport unit values to 0 if the page has been left and is returned to after 60 seconds.
>Safari & iOS Safari (both 6 and 7) does not support viewport units for border widths
>Chrome does not support viewport units for border widths
>vh on iOS is reported to include the height of the bottom toolbar in the height calculation
Sadly, this is not appropriate in my case.

Comment: @user8478480 can you use Javascript then ?